# WPF Command Binding on Code Behind problem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command

I am new to WPF and I have created a WPF Application. In that application, I have a UserControl that contain a button as below,

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:AppViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Btn_Contact" Command="{Binding BookVM.LoadContactsCommand}" Click="Btn_Contact_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

And My AppViewModel Class is as below

```
public AppViewModel()
    {
        var dataService = new JsonContactDataService();                   
        BookVM = new BookViewModel(dataService);
        CurrentView = BookVM;
    }
```

My problem is I want this UserControl to run command of the Btn_Contact automatically when the UserControl is loaded instead of clicking the button. I have try to write the command binding on the UserControl code-behind but it does not worked.

```
public UserControlMemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Btn_Contact.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        Btn_Contact.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("BookVM.LoadContactsCommand"));
    }
```

Comment: So the Button Click is pointing to a Function/Command - "BookVM.LoadContactsCommand"  -- why dont you call the target function instead of raising a Click Event?

Comment: I agree. Don't fake click events when there are no clicks. There is a loaded event for your user control. And you can execute every ICommand. BookVM.LoadContactsCommand.Execute(). That's all you have to do in code behind

Comment: ICommand. BookVM. LoadContactsCommand. Execute(): is not working out.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form:

```
public UserControlMemo()
{
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataContext is AppViewModel viewModel) 
        viewModel.BookVM.LoadContactsCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

Comment: Tq very much sir. Thats what i need.